# Is value returned by java.util.Date.getTime() same as java.time.ZonedDateTime.getEpochSeconds()?

Tags: java, java-time, java.util.date

I have a legacy application that is passing Date using

> java.util.Date

and a new service that is providing date using

> java.time.ZonedDateTime

.
My use case is to compare both the dates and determine which one is most recent.
Can I use `java.util.Date.getTime()/1000` and `java.time.ZonedDateTime.getEpochSeconds()` and compare the resulting values from both these methods?
Am I missing anything by comparing the seconds from both of these packages?

Comment: If you have `java.util.Date a` try `ZonedDateTime a1 = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(a.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());` and compare two `ZonedDateTime`(s). `java.util.Date` is broken. Replace it as soon as you can.

Comment: You comparison loses precision but is otherwise correct (only inaccurate).

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
myJavaUtilDate
.toInstant()
.isBefore(
    myZonedDateTime
    .toInstant()
)
```

## `Instant`

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72064351/is-value-returned-by-java-util-date-gettime-same-as-java-time-zoneddatetime-ge/72064484#comment127333259_72064351), the most graceful approach uses [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html). That class represents a moment as seen in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

### Convert

The `java.util.Date` is a terribly flawed class that is now legacy. Avoid whenever possible. But if handed an object if that class,  call the new conversion methods added to the old legacy date-time classes.

Be aware that `Date` has a resolution of mere [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond).

```
Instant x = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

And your [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object can be adjusted to UTC by extracting an `Instant`. Both of these classes resolve to nanoseconds.

```
Instant y = myZonedDateTime.toInstant() ;
```

### Compare

Compare with `isBefore` or `IsAfter` methods.

```
if ( x.isBefore ( y ) ) { … }
```